# Android Fragments UI Design Example

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

I am getting error following error. give me a suggestion if you faced the same issue.

```
fragmentslayout\app\src\main\java\com\example\fragmentslayout\app\MainActivity.java
Error:(9, 8) error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method Message(String) in Communicator
fragmentslayout\app\src\main\java\com\example\fragmentslayout\app\MyListFragment.java
Error:(23, 28) error: incompatible types: OnItemSelectedListener cannot be converted to Communicator
```

My Code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fragmentslayout.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Communicator
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRssItemSelected(String OS_Name) {
        DetailFragment detailfragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.detail_Fragment);
        if (detailfragment != null && detailfragment.isInLayout()) {
            detailfragment.setText(OS_Name);
        }

    }
}
```

**DetailFragment.java**

```
package com.example.fragmentslayout.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    // we call this method when button from listfragment is clicked
    public void setText(String item) {
        TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.display_tv);
        view.setText(item);
    }
}
```

**MyListFragment.java**

```
package com.example.fragmentslayout.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
{

    private Communicator communicator;

    Button android_btn, ios_btn, windows_btn;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof Communicator) {
            communicator = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implemenet MyListFragment.Communicator");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        // Initialize Views
        android_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.android_btn_id);
        ios_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ios_btn_id);
        windows_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.windows_btn_id);

        // set on click Listeners for buttons
        android_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        ios_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        windows_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void Message(String OS_Name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.android_btn_id:
                updateFragment("Android");
                break;

            case R.id.ios_btn_id:
                updateFragment("IOS");
                break;

            case R.id.windows_btn_id:
                updateFragment("Windows");
                break;
        }

    }

    private void updateFragment(String OS_Name) {
        communicator.Message(OS_Name);
    }

}
```

**Communicator Interface**

```
package com.example.fragmentslayout.app;

public interface Communicator {
    public void Message(String tutUri);
}
```

Layout:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.example.fragmentslayout.app.MyListFragment" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detail_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="com.example.fragmentslayout.app.DetailFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

**detail_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF99"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CCFF99"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/android_btn_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ios_btn_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="IOS" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/windows_btn_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Windows" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` implements `Communicator`,so you must override abstract method `Message(String)`. Just add the method `Message(String)` to your `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity implements Communicator, is your Communicator in activity same Communicator in fragment!!,so you must override abstract method Message(String), move your code in onRssItemSelected(string) function to new message function

just add this function to mainactivity

```
@Override
public void Message(String OS_Name) {
    DetailFragment detailfragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detail_Fragment);
    if (detailfragment != null && detailfragment.isInLayout()) {
        detailfragment.setText(OS_Name);
    }

}
```